# How get report file from docker and insert to gitlab repository

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created docker which runs automated tests. I run it by `gitlab script`. All works except the report file. I cannot get a report file from docker and insert it to the repository. Command `docker cp` not working. My GitLab script and docker file:

Gitlab script:

```yaml
stages:
 - test
test:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
      command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # See https://github.com/docker-library/docker/pull/166
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "xxx" -p "yyy" docker.io
  script: 
    - docker run --name authContainer "rrr/image:0.0.1"
  after_script:
    - docker cp authContainer:/artifacts $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/test-result.xml
    reports:
      junit:
         - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/test-result.xml
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1

COPY /publish  /Spinelle.AutomaticTests
WORKDIR /Spinelle.AutomaticTests

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install unzip

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN unzip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver -d /Spinelle.AutomaticTests
RUN chmod 777 /Spinelle.AutomaticTests 

CMD dotnet vstest /Parallel Spinelle.AutomaticTests.dll --TestAdapterPath:. --logger:"nunit;LogFilePath=/artifacts/test-result.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
```

Comment: How do you know that `docker cp` is not working? Perhaps a path may be wrong elsewhere? Try this: Check that there is data in the path `authContainer:/artifacts` as the first line of your `after_script`: `ls authContainer:/artifacts` Then check `ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR/artifacts/` after the current line in the `after_script`

Comment: `Docker cp` working on my local machine(copy report to designated destination). I think its problem with copy it to the repository

Comment: I am not sure right now, but: Try running the `docker cp` not in the `after_script`, but in the `script`-section. Artifacts can only be grabbed from resources created in the `script`-Section as `after_script` is run within a new session.